# JavaScript Close/Redirect Page Upon URL Change

Tags: javascript

I have a frame with a page from a different domain.  Sometimes, that page likes to use a frame-buster to break out of its frame and hijack my entire page.

I have been experimenting with different ways to handle what happens when this frame wants to break out.  What I have determined would be the best way to handle this is to use JavaScript to determine when the parent page url changes (via onunload) I want to direct the user back to my homepage or close the page altogether.  I am a php dev and don't really ever use JavaScript.

I have tried using  but that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:
   `<script>`
   `window.onunload=function() {`
   `return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave the current page?');`
   `}`
`</script>`

Comment: Eh I don't want to just ask the user if they want to leave the page, I want to redirect them to another page, maybe if they click yes?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813455/is-it-possible-for-onunload-confirm-to-open-a-new-url-in-the-same-window

Comment: The parent frame still directs to the frame-busted page with that code.  I tried something very similar with no avail.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369498/how-to-prevent-iframe-from-redirecting-top-level-window